# How to add events in FullCalender dynamically using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using the following code and I got this error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

After events tag open. Please find the solution.
The code is

```
followuplimit = 3;
        $('.calendar').fullCalendar({
          defaultDate: today,
          selectable: false,
          editable: false,
          height: 400,
          eventLimit: true,
          events: [
            for(var q=0;q<data.result.lead.length;q++){
              {      
                title: data.result.lead[n].ids,
                start: date('Y-m-d',strtotime(data.result.lead[n].followup_date)),
                if(data.result.lead[n].ids >= followuplimit) {
                backgroundColor    : '#FF0000',
                borderColor    : '#FF0000'
                } else { 
                backgroundColor    : '#008C1F',
                borderColor    : '#008C1F'
                } 
              },
            }
          ],
        });
```

Comment: You're getting a syntax error because you have invalid syntax.  You're trying to put an `if` block inside an array declaration.  It's not clear why you're *trying* to do that.

Comment: because i need to mark multiple dates in single calendar thats why i am using like this.

Comment: "Mark multiple dates" implies that you simply want an array.  For an example, consult the documentation of the product you're using: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-array  An array is simply an array, what's not clear is why you have *an if statement* there.  Just remove that `if` statement and make your array of events.

Comment: @TheresaVincent make the if statement before like this: `var bob = {}; if (data.result.datepicker) bob = { great: true; }` then (much further down inside your `$('.calendar').fullCalendar`)  use `events: [          bob ]`

Answer (score 0):

This part is not correct

```
events: [
    if(data.result.datepicker){
    } 
],
```

It should look more like this:

```
var myEvent = {};
if (data.result.datepicker) {
    myEvent = {someIndex: someValue};
}

...
    events: [
        myEvent
    ],
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`if` is invalid where you use it how you use it. You might want to use the [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator instead:

```
$('.calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: today,
    selectable: false,
    editable: false,
    height: 400,
    eventLimit: true,
    events: data.result.datepicker ? [
        { } 
    ] : [],
});
```